# Google Container Engine (Kubernetes): Websocket (Socket.io) not working on multiple replicas

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am new to Google Container Engine (GKE). When run on `localhost` it's working fine but when I deploy to production with GKE I got websocket error.

My node app is develop with `Hapi.js` and `Socket.io` and my structure is shown in image below.

[Application Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cUsG.png)

I'm using Glue to compose Hapi server. Below is my `manifest.json`

```
{
...
"connections": [
    {
      "host": "app",
      "address": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 8000,
      "labels": ["api"],
      "routes": {
        "cors": false,
        "security": {
          "hsts": false,
          "xframe": true,
          "xss": true,
          "noOpen": true,
          "noSniff": true
        }
      },
      "router": {
        "stripTrailingSlash": true
      },
      "load": {
        "maxHeapUsedBytes": 1073741824,
        "maxRssBytes": 1610612736,
        "maxEventLoopDelay": 5000
      }
    },
    {
      "host": "app",
      "address": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 8099,
      "labels": ["web"],
      "routes": {
        "cors": true,
        "security": {
          "hsts": false,
          "xframe": true,
          "xss": true,
          "noOpen": true,
          "noSniff": true
        }
      },
      "router": {
        "stripTrailingSlash": true
      },
      "load": {
        "maxHeapUsedBytes": 1073741824,
        "maxRssBytes": 1610612736,
        "maxEventLoopDelay": 5000
      }
    },
    {
      "host": "app",
      "address": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 8999,
      "labels": ["admin"],
      "routes": {
        "cors": true,
        "security": {
          "hsts": false,
          "xframe": true,
          "xss": true,
          "noOpen": true,
          "noSniff": true
        }
      },
      "router": {
        "stripTrailingSlash": true
      },
      "load": {
        "maxHeapUsedBytes": 1073741824,
        "maxRssBytes": 1610612736,
        "maxEventLoopDelay": 5000
      },
      "state": {
        "ttl": null,
        "isSecure": false,
        "isHttpOnly": true,
        "path": null,
        "domain": null,
        "encoding": "none",
        "clearInvalid": false,
        "strictHeader": true
      }
    }
  ],
...
}
```

And my `nginx.conf`

```
worker_processes                5; ## Default: 1
worker_rlimit_nofile            8192;
error_log                       /dev/stdout info;

events {
  worker_connections            4096; ## Default: 1024
}

http {
    access_log                  /dev/stdout;

    server {
        listen                  80          default_server;
        listen                  [::]:80     default_server;

        # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved Permanently response.
        return                  301         https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen                  443         ssl default_server;
        listen                  [::]:443    ssl default_server;
        server_name             _;

        # Configure ssl
        ssl_certificate         /etc/secret/ssl/myapp.com.csr;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/secret/ssl/myapp.com.key;
        include                 /etc/nginx/ssl-params.conf;
    }

    server {
        listen                  443         ssl;
        listen                  [::]:443    ssl;
        server_name             api.myapp.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass          http://api_app/;
            proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            # Handle Web Socket connections
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade     $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection  "upgrade";
        }
    }

    server {
        listen                  443         ssl;
        listen                  [::]:443    ssl;
        server_name             myapp.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass          http://web_app/;
            proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            # Handle Web Socket connections
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade     $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection  "upgrade";
        }
    }

    server {
        listen                  443         ssl;
        listen                  [::]:443    ssl;
        server_name             admin.myapp.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass          http://admin_app/;
            proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            # Handle Web Socket connections
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade     $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection  "upgrade";
        }
    }

    # Define your "upstream" servers - the
    # servers request will be sent to
    upstream api_app {
        server                  localhost:8000;
    }

    upstream web_app {
        server                  localhost:8099;
    }

    upstream admin_app {
        server                  localhost:8999;
    }
}
```

Kubernetes service `app-service.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-nginx
  labels:
    app: app-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    # The port that this service should serve on.
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
      name: https
  # Label keys and values that must match in order to receive traffic for this service.
  selector:
    app: app-nginx
```

Kubernetes Deployment `app-deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: us.gcr.io/myproject/nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: http
            - containerPort: 443
              name: https
          volumeMounts:
              # This name must match the volumes.name below.
            - name: ssl-secret
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /etc/secret/ssl
        - name: app
          image: us.gcr.io/myproject/bts-server
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
              name: api
            - containerPort: 8099
              name: web
            - containerPort: 8999
              name: admin
          volumeMounts:
              # This name must match the volumes.name below.
            - name: client-secret
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /etc/secret/client
            - name: admin-secret
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /etc/secret/admin
      volumes:
        - name: ssl-secret
          secret:
            secretName: ssl-key-secret
        - name: client-secret
          secret:
            secretName: client-key-secret
        - name: admin-secret
          secret:
            secretName: admin-key-secret
```

And I'm using `Cloudflare SSL full strict`.

Error get from Browser console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.myapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=4Ky-y9K7J0XotrBFAAAQ' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
https://api.myapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LYByND2&sid=4Ky-y9K7J0XotrBFAAAQ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
VM50:35 WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.myapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=FsCGx-UE7ohrsSSqAAAT' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502WrappedWebSocket @ VM50:35WS.doOpen @ socket.io.js:6605Transport.open @ socket.io.js:4695Socket.probe @ socket.io.js:3465Socket.onOpen @ socket.io.js:3486Socket.onHandshake @ socket.io.js:3546Socket.onPacket @ socket.io.js:3508(anonymous function) @ socket.io.js:3341Emitter.emit @ socket.io.js:6102Transport.onPacket @ socket.io.js:4760callback @ socket.io.js:4510(anonymous function) @ socket.io.js:5385exports.decodePayloadAsBinary @ socket.io.js:5384exports.decodePayload @ socket.io.js:5152Polling.onData @ socket.io.js:4514(anonymous function) @ socket.io.js:4070Emitter.emit @ socket.io.js:6102Request.onData @ socket.io.js:4231Request.onLoad @ socket.io.js:4312xhr.onreadystatechange @ socket.io.js:4184
socket.io.js:4196 GET https://api.myapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LYByNpy&sid=FsCGx-UE7ohrsSSqAAAT 400 ()
```

And here is Nginx's logs:

```
[22/Nov/2016:12:10:19 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=MGc--oncQbQI6NOZAAAX HTTP/1.1" 101 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
10.8.0.1 - - [22/Nov/2016:12:10:19 +0000] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LYByQBw&sid=MGc--oncQbQI6NOZAAAX HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "https://myapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
10.128.0.2 - - [22/Nov/2016:12:10:20 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LYByQKp HTTP/1.1" 200 101 "https://myapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
10.8.0.1 - - [22/Nov/2016:12:10:21 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LYByQWo&sid=c5nkusT9fEPRsu2rAAAY HTTP/1.1" 200 24 "https://myapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
2016/11/22 12:10:21 [error] 6#6: *157 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.8.0.1, server: api.myapp.com, request: "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LYByQaN&sid=c5nkusT9fEPRsu2rAAAY HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LYByQaN&sid=c5nkusT9fEPRsu2rAAAY", host: "api.myapp.com", referrer: "https://myapp.com/"
2016/11/22 12:10:21 [warn] 6#6: *157 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 10.8.0.1, server: api.myapp.com, request: "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LYByQaN&sid=c5nkusT9fEPRsu2rAAAY HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LYByQaN&sid=c5nkusT9fEPRsu2rAAAY", host: "api.myapp.com", referrer: "https://myapp.com/"
10.8.0.1 - - [22/Nov/2016:12:10:22 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LYByQaN&sid=c5nkusT9fEPRsu2rAAAY HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "https://myapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
```

**UPDATE**

When I change `replicas` to `1` in `app-deployment.yaml` it's work. But I think it's not a good solution. I need **3 replicas**.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: app-nginx
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: app-nginx
```

**How to make it work with 3 replicas?**

Comment: Does NGINX have any defined ingress rules? Keep in mind that there is no websocket support at the L7 LB yet. Adding the 

type: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"

Should do it

Comment: Thank @George. I have no Ingress. Can you give me a more detail how to make it work in my case?

Comment: @George, I using L4 LB. So, I think the problem is `sessionAffinity`. Can we define `Load distribution algorithm` for Kubernetes Service?
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/#load_distribution_algorithm

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. The fact that 1 replica out of 3 is working is a bit weird, however is it possible to rewrite your nginx config to use ip, not dns (like 127.0.0.1 instead 'localhost') and make sure that it is started or listening on the specified port.

Comment: Sorry @George for late reply. I will try it. But It's possible to set  `sessionAffinity` in `Service`?

Comment: In Kubernetes, load balancing is done by kube-proxy. The default settings send traffic randomly to one of the backend pods. Client-IP based session affinity can be selected by setting service.spec.sessionAffinity to ClientIP (the default value is None) in the Kubernetes service config.

Comment: Thank @George, I'll try it now and will feedback the result.

Comment: @George, I have config to use `sessionAffinity: ClientIP`. Some time it's work, some time does not. Does not work on first load page and when I'm press `Ctrl+F5`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After I update Kubernetes service template to use `sessionAffinity: ClientIP` it works now. But just get some error when first press `Ctrl + F5` and on second press it's work fine.

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

**However, I still get data from server. So I think it's okay.**

**Updated Service template**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-nginx
  labels:
    app: app-nginx
spec:
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    # The port that this service should serve on.
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
      name: https
  # Label keys and values that must match in order
  # to receive traffic for this service.
  selector:
    app: app-nginx
```

Comment: Thanks ! I was facing same issue and 'sessionAffinity: ClientIP' solved this issue. Your post saved my time.

Comment: @NikhilMaheshwari, so glad to hear that