# GCE, Kubernetes with Socket.IO, NodeJs not enough resources

Tags: node.js, socket.io, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to migrate a real-time socket.io NodeJs application to Kubernetes cluster on GCP. I am facing an issue while maintaining the session stickiness (by CLIENT IP) with the normal load balancer. I found out that I need to use the nginx-ingress controller for this. There is no proper documentation or tutorial available. If anyone can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

**UPDATED**
I am looking for **CLIENT IP** session stickiness.

Comment: There is a similar kind of question available [HERE] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743432/google-container-engine-kubernetes-websocket-socket-io-not-working-on-multi).

Comment: This not-yet-answered but similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48339551/4636715) points [this example](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/27c863085e2503e5f3249b596f24529fc2488baa/docs/examples/affinity/cookie). May help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743432/google-container-engine-kubernetes-websocket-socket-io-not-working-on-multi), you can add a line to your service config file spec.sessionAffinity: ClientIP which should keep client IP stickiness